# Python connection with database

Tags: python, mysql, database, connection

I am trying to connect the database mysql to mycode but i don't know what is the problen i have treid many solution but still confuse if any body can help ?
`

```
e:\hotelManagnment\customer.py:38: DeprecationWarning: ANTIALIAS is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use Resampling.LANCZOS instead.
  img2=img2.resize((100,40),Image.ANTIALIAS)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\hotelManagnment\customer.py", line 262, in <module>
    obj=Cust_Win(root)
  File "e:\hotelManagnment\customer.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.fetch_data()
  File "e:\hotelManagnment\customer.py", line 245, in fetch_data
    conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",username="root",password="",database="managment")
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\pooling.py", line 287, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 137, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1108, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 544, in _open_connection
    self.set_converter_class(self._converter_class)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1284, in set_converter_class
    self.converter = convclass(charset_name, self._use_unicode)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 136, in __init__
    MySQLConverterBase.__init__(self, charset, use_unicode, str_fallback)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.set_charset(charset)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 73, in set_charset
    self.charset_id = CharacterSet.get_charset_info(self.charset)[0]
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\constants.py", line 775, in get_charset_info
    info = cls.get_default_collation(charset)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\constants.py", line 746, in get_default_collation
    raise ProgrammingError(f"Character set '{charset}' unsupported")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Character set 'utf8' unsupported
```

`

Comment: What versions of MySQL and mysql-connector-python are you using?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate question. Check this for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73244027/character-set-utf8-unsupported-in-python-mysql-connector